# MS Access SQL convert Rows to Columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I need some help with converting an MS Access table with data in Rows into Columns. Created some sample data table that suits my scenario. I need to convert "**Table 1**" to "**Table 3**". If possible using the "**Table 2**" to identify the column order of the Fruits.
[image]

I think this can be done using Pivot option in SQL Server. How can I achieve the same in Access Database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Column Order is dictated by value in the column header. Could concatenate Fruit and Order fields:
`Order & "-" & Fruit AS OrderFruit`.

Use query designer to build query that joins Table1 and Table2 on Fruit fields with that calculated field and switch to CROSSTAB to complete.

Answer (score 1):

Consider MS Access' [crosstab](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8) query which uses `TRANSFORM` and `PIVOT` clauses. The `IN` list in `PIVOT` specifies the order and appearance (omit or not) of columns.

```
TRANSFORM MAX(t1.Export) AS MaxExport
SELECT t1.Country
FROM table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.Country
PIVOT t1.Fruit IN ('Apple', 'Kiwi', 'Mango', 'Grapes', 'Pear')
```

For needed order with number period column headers, simply join the second table and concatenate `Order` and `Fruit` columns in `PIVOT` clause:

```
TRANSFORM MAX(t1.Export) AS MaxExport
SELECT t1.Country
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
   t1.Fruit = t2.Fruit
GROUP BY t1.Country
PIVOT t2.[Order] & "." & t1.Fruit
```

Comment: Thanks Parfait. It did work. I just need to join the Table 2 to dictate the order. The original data has a long list of questions which will be transformed into columns. I replaced the Order column with FruitOrder with the Order number concatenated at first (e.g - "1.Apple") Any idea how to join and make this might work?

TRANSFORM MAX(t1.Export) AS MaxExport
SELECT t1.Country
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Fruit = t2.Fruit;
GROUP BY t1.Country
PIVOT t2.FruitOrder

Comment: And what went wrong with your attempted query? See extended answer to concatenate two columns in `PIVOT`?